# Get a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to get a list of dictionaries where each dictionary contain two keys (one for `card_name` and one for `card_type`).

```py
suits = [
     'Clubs',
     'Diamonds',
     'Hearts',
     'Spades',
]

cards = [
     'Ace',
     '2',
     '3',
     '4',
     '5',
     '6',
     '7',
     '8',
     '9',
     '10',
     'Jack',
     'Queen',
     'King',
]

card_deck = []
comb = {}

for i in range(len(cards)):
    for l in range(len(suits)):
        comb['card_name'] = cards[i]
        comb['card_type'] = suits[l]
        card_deck.append(comb)
print(card_deck)
```

Comment: what is your sample output?

Answer (score 0):

```
suits = [ 'Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades', ]
cards = [ 'Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 
'Queen', 'King', ] 

card_deck = []
comb = {}

# map each suit to all members of cards
for suit in suits:
  for card in cards:
    comb[suit] = card
    cards.remove(card)
    card_deck.append(comb)


print(card_deck)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).